C++ Generic Function to Read 2D Vector from Standard Input
I'm trying to write a generic function in C++ that takes a matrix input from standard input and converts it into a vector<vector>. The input format is supposed to be a string representing a 2D array, for example: [[5, 6], [7, 8]]. The function should handle different types (e.g., int, string, bool), and populate the vector correctly.
Here's the code I wrote:
template<typename T>
vector<vector<T>> read2DVectorFromStdin() {
    string input;
    getline(cin, input);

    // Remove all spaces from the input
    input.erase(remove_if(input.begin(), input.end(), ::isspace), input.end());

    vector<vector<T>> matrix;
    stringstream ss(input);
    char ch;

    // Check if input starts and ends with square brackets
    if (input.front() != '[' || input.back() != ']') {
        cerr << "Invalid format! Input should start with '[' and end with ']'." << endl;
        return matrix;
    }

    // Remove the outer square brackets
    ss.ignore(1); // Ignore the first '['

    while (ss >> ch) {
        if (ch == '[') {
            vector<T> row;
            T value;
            string token;

            while (ss.peek() != ']') {
                getline(ss, token, ',');

                // Handle the case where the token ends with ']'
                size_t pos = token.find(']');
                if (pos != string::npos) {
                    token = token.substr(0, pos);
                }

                stringstream tokenStream(token);
                if constexpr (is_same<T, string>::value) {
                    // Remove leading and trailing spaces
                    token.erase(remove_if(token.begin(), token.end(), ::isspace), token.end());
                    // Check for and remove quotes
                    if (token.front() == '"' && token.back() == '"') {
                        token = token.substr(1, token.length() - 2);
                    }
                    row.push_back(token);
                }
                else if constexpr (is_same<T, bool>::value) {
                    // Convert to lowercase for easier comparison
                    transform(token.begin(), token.end(), token.begin(), [](unsigned char c) { return tolower(c); });

                    // Trim leading and trailing spaces
                    auto start = token.find_first_not_of(' ');
                    if (start != string::npos) {
                        token = token.substr(start);
                    }

                    auto end = token.find_last_not_of(' ');
                    if (end != string::npos) {
                        token = token.substr(0, end + 1);
                    }

                    if (token == "true" || token == "1") {
                        value = true;
                    }
                    else if (token == "false" || token == "0") {
                        value = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        cerr << "Invalid input for boolean: -" << token << "-" << endl;
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                    row.push_back(value);
                }
                else {
                    tokenStream >> value;
                    if (!tokenStream) {
                        cerr << "Invalid input: " << token << endl;
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                    row.push_back(value);
                }
                ss.ignore();
            }

            matrix.push_back(row);
        }
        if (ss.peek() == ',') {
            ss.ignore(); // Ignore the comma between row definitions
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}

The issue I'm facing is that the function seems to ignore the last line of input. For example, with the input [[5, 6], [7, 8]], the function outputs:
5 6
Instead of the expected output:
5 6
7 8

On the first iteration, your loop consumes 5,, then ss.ignore() call (the one above matrix.push_back(row)) eats 6. So next you see the closing bracket, and push a one-element row containing just 5. The same repeats with [7, 8] - you accept 7 and ignore 8.

You try to rely on ss.peek() != ']' to detect when a row ends - but you swallow the closing bracket in getline(ss, token, ',') (you even had to write special code to remove it from the token), so you never actually see it.

As correctly pointed out by @Igor Tandetnik, the two main issues in your code are:

The ss.ignore() after row.push_back(value); in the following part -

else {
    tokenStream >> value;
    if (!tokenStream) {
        cerr << "Invalid input: " << token << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    row.push_back(value);
}
ss.ignore(); // This omits the 6

Because you have provided ',' as you delimiter here, getline(ss, token, ',') will return the string until ','. This means that the ',' will itself be excluded. Therefore, the next item will be '6' instead of ','. The ss.ignore() will remove ignore the '6' and proceed with the next character as ']'. Therefore, '6' will never get added.

Removing the ss.ignore() there would lead to another issue. This time, getline(ss, token, ',') will include the last number in the vector along with ']'. This means that for a vector '[5, 6]', the value of token in the second iteration will be '6]'. After that, you remove the ']' using -

size_t pos = token.find(']');
if (pos != string::npos) {
    token = token.substr(0, pos);
}

Solution -
One possible solution is to remove the ss.ignore() and have a flag to check the end of vector instead of ss.peek() != ']'. Something like this -
template<typename T>
vector<vector<T>> read2DVectorFromStdin() {
    string input = "[[5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]]";
    //getline(cin, input);

    // Remove all spaces from the input
    input.erase(remove_if(input.begin(), input.end(), ::isspace), input.end());

    vector<vector<T>> matrix;
    stringstream ss(input);
    char ch;

    // Check if input starts and ends with square brackets
    if (input.front() != '[' || input.back() != ']') {
        cerr << "Invalid format! Input should start with '[' and end with ']'." << endl;
        return matrix;
    }

    // Remove the outer square brackets
    ss.ignore(1); // Ignore the first '['

    while (ss >> ch) {
        if (ch == '[') {
            vector<T> row;
            T value;
            string token;

            bool vecEndFound = false; // flag to check the end of vector
            
            while (!vecEndFound) {
                getline(ss, token, ',');

                // Handle the case where the token ends with ']'
                size_t pos = token.find(']');
                if (pos != string::npos) {
                    token = token.substr(0, pos);
                    vecEndFound = true; // set it to true when ']' is found
                }

                std::stringstream tokenStream(token);
                if constexpr (is_same<T, string>::value) {
                    // Remove leading and trailing spaces
                    token.erase(remove_if(token.begin(), token.end(), ::isspace), token.end());
                    // Check for and remove quotes
                    if (token.front() == '"' && token.back() == '"') {
                        token = token.substr(1, token.length() - 2);
                    }
                    row.push_back(token);
                }
                else if constexpr (is_same<T, bool>::value) {
                    // Convert to lowercase for easier comparison
                    transform(token.begin(), token.end(), token.begin(), [](unsigned char c) { return tolower(c); });

                    // Trim leading and trailing spaces
                    auto start = token.find_first_not_of(' ');
                    if (start != string::npos) {
                        token = token.substr(start);
                    }

                    auto end = token.find_last_not_of(' ');
                    if (end != string::npos) {
                        token = token.substr(0, end + 1);
                    }

                    if (token == "true" || token == "1") {
                        value = true;
                    }
                    else if (token == "false" || token == "0") {
                        value = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        cerr << "Invalid input for boolean: -" << token << "-" << endl;
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                    row.push_back(value);
                }
                else {
                    tokenStream >> value;
                    if (!tokenStream) {
                        cerr << "Invalid input: " << token << endl;
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                    row.push_back(value);
                }
            }
            // remove the ss.ignore() from here.
            matrix.push_back(row);
        }
        if (ss.peek() == ',') {
            ss.ignore(); // Ignore the comma between row definitions
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}

Hope this helps.
